# logback.xml from imported jar cause a warning

Tags: java, neo4j, logback

I'm using Neo4j server in my app, starting embedded graph db with REST server.
Now the neo4j-server artifact comes with `logback.xml` in it.
I'm also using logback for logging => 
I get

```
16:17:13,233 |-WARN in - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
16:17:13,233 |-WARN in - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [file:/D:/dev/graph-server/target/classes/logback.xml]
16:17:13,233 |-WARN in - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/C:/Users/user123/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/app/neo4j-server/1.8/neo4j-server-1.8.jar!/logback.xml]
```

Warning that `logback.xml` occurs multiple times.

What should I do? I don't want to turn off logback status logging and it's a bit disturbing to see this message every time I start the app.

Thanks.

Alex

P.S. - My logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <Target>System.out</Target>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss } [%t] %-5p %logger{32} - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.myapp" level="INFO"/>
    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I just answered to exclude the logback dependency from your neo4j artifact, but then I saw they really seem to include that file in the jar, not as a dependency. I think this might be a bug in the neo4j-server, just like this was a bug: https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff/issues/34 So you might want to ask the neo4j-guys if this was intentional. I doubt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing this is on Neo4j's roadmap but there's no ETA right now. As a workaround you could unpack the jar, remove `logback.xml` and repack it, and then supply `logback.xml` yourself on the classpath.

Answer (score 5):

Just rename your logback.xml to logback-test.xml and it will pick up yours